# Is there any problem unhooking a delegate from an event which was never hooked?

Tags: c#, .net, events

I am using standard windows forms controls under C#.

I have two controls which are different ways of setting a single value.  Thus when one is changed, the changed event handler computes a value for the other and sets it.  So I need to unhook the change event on the second control temporarily to prevent looping (A changes B, B is changed so it changes A, A is changed...).  There are also some other situations where I need to stop the change event.  So there are several places where I need to unhook the event, and only one place where it needs to be hooked.

My question is: do I need to keep track of whether the event has been hooked or can I just unhook it as many times as I like and only occasionally hook it again?  (Is there any documentation that addresses this?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unhooking an event handler that was never registered using the `-=` operator won't give you any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Ya, you can unhook it as many times as you want, no exceptions will be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

This will loop through and unhook any subscribed methods:

```
Delegate[] subscribers = myEvent.GetInvocationList();

    for(int i = 0; i < subscribers.Length; i++)

    {

    myEvent -= subscribers[i] as yourDelegateType;

    }
```

However, I think you should be able to avoid the looping problem by writing a single handler with logic to determine how the data should be modified.  This would be cleaner and more maintainable.

Comment: I was about to post something similar regarding a more maintainable solution.  In particular, I wouldn't like to be the developer who comes along later to maintain code that assigns and removes handlers instead of using a flag, or a single handler.